# How to customize the xlab name in plot() in R?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to create a function to draw scatterplots of variables, something like the following:

```
plotting = function(x,y){

   plot(x, y,
        main= "PM10 and Electricity use",
        ylab= "",
        xlab= "",
        col= "blue", pch = 19, cex = 1, lty = "solid", lwd = 2)

}

y = PM10
x = Total_E*population

plotting(x,y)
```

(Note: PM10, Total_E, population are all vectors of numbers.)

Is that possible to change `xlab`, `ylab` to the names of the variables, say `ylab` to "PM10", and `xlab` to "Total_E*population" or even "Total_E times population"?

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for non-standard evaluation. This is accomplished with `substitute` and `deparse`. ...

```
plotting <- function(x, y) {
  plot(x, y, main = "PM10 and Electricity use",
    ylab = deparse(substitute(y)), 
    xlab = deparse(substitute(x))
  )
}
```

Comment: Edited add missing parens for plot function.

Comment: @Chumoon you should accept the answer if it helped you to award misspelled the deserved points :)